# Horizontal Scroll Bar Appears - Even Div's Width=100%

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to fit a div into the browser's working area by setting div's
width and height as 100 %. Despite i am getting a vertical and horizontal scroll bars
on the screen.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#test{ width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red; }
body{ margin:0; padding:0; }
```

I also tried this with scripting, But same result returned.

SCRIPT:

```
$('#test').css({'width':$(window).width(),'height':$(window).height()});
```

I Have Been Testing This With IE9. Any Ideas To Avoid This.?

Comment: Have you tried doing `html {padding: 0;}`? And have you tried setting `overflow: none;` on the `body`? I currently can't test in IE9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution Obtained:**
 

The Problem is, i Forgot to specify the **border attribute for Body**

```
    body{ margin:0; padding:0; border:0;}
```

Now its Fine, The **H and V scroll bar Got Vanished**.
 Any way Thank you guys for your timely response.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on IE version / quirks mode, either:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').css('height', $(window).innerHeight());
    });
```

or

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').css('height', document.body.clientHeight);
    });
```

will work. You can do the same with widths as well.

```
    $(window).innerWidth();
    document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Using your code & my code in IE 9 worked good for me. Since it apparently didn't work for you, my only other suggestion is to **ensure there are no other borders/margins/paddings that could be interfering.**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hi</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ margin:0; padding:0; }
        #test{ width:100%; height:100%; background-color:red; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#test').css('height', $(window).innerHeight());
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ 

    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 

}

#test{ 

    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:none;
    background-color:red; 

}
```

**or**

```
#test{ 

    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border:none;
    background-color:red;


}
```